# Parsing the JSON Value

Tags: json

Currently I am getting an response of List when I converted to JSON using object mapper (jackson API)

```
{"message":"Result was Successfull","Response":"[{\"empID\":\"1106\",\"empName\":null,\"empSal\":231.67,\"emp\":0.0,\"empBonus\":695.0},{\"empID\":\"7898\",\"empName\":null,\"empSal\":9900.0,\"emp\":0.0,\"empBonus\":9700.0}]"}
```

I am expecting the resultant set as shown below

```
{"Response": Sucessfull,
   1106 {
        "empName":null,
        "empSal":231.67,
        "empBonus":695.0
        },
    7868
        {
         "empName":null,
         "empSal":990.67,
         "empBonus":455.0
        }
}
```

Comment: How are your parsing the JSON value?

Comment: Please, post your code. We need to see how you apply the mapper.

Comment: Expected json string is wrong. I mean not in proper format. e.g. json keys must be in quotes ("key");